# Anchor TextView containing dynamic content and auto-resize text

Tags: java, android, resize, textview, anchor

I have a textview with an integer which can increase or decrease depending on the gesture performed on the screen. However, as the integer increases or decreases, the position of the number on the screen changes since some numbers have less width than other numbers. I have already used gravity to center the number in the textview.

Specifically, when the number is changed from 2 to 1, the entire number shifts to the left.

Also, since i have 2 textviews beside each other, when they both have double digit numbers, they start to overlap. Is there a way to auto resize the text?

An ideal solution would be one where if the textview was a rectangle, that rectangle would be anchored to the position and as the number changes it can only change inside of that area and if it doesnt fit, the text is resized down to lower font size.

Comment: Post some of your code

Comment: Post your layout if you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 work around for solving this problem. It depends on you which you want to prefer.

See below :

1. Use LinearLayout

   ```
   <LinearLayout>

         <TextView ONE/>
                                        //assign weight property
         <TextView TWO/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Use Marquee property

   Use marquee property to your both textviews, so those'll marquee in particular area

Comment: can you explain in detail how each of those work and how to implement them?

Comment: assign weight to your linearlayout "android:weightsum=2", assigning weight to both textviews "textview1/2" -> android:weight=1 for each textview.

Comment: Google for set Marquee property for textview, you will get good blogs

Comment: If you are fine  with my answer, then you should accept it. So other can follow the same answer, this is stackoverflow

Comment: i accepted the answer but cannot up vote it as i don't have enough reputation points but thanks for the solution. Linear layout works like a charm although it is very restrictive in where you can place views.